# how to wide gamut ,convert from 8bit to 10bit

Tags: c++, opencv, x264, 8-bit, hdr

1. I know that the video we watched on the tv is compressed.The range
   of the gamut will be narrow.I want to know if there is a magical way
   can achieve the extending.Dolby claimd the Perceptual
   Quantizer(PQ)EOTE .there is two function Eg.[the Perceptual
   Quantizer(PQ)EOTE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRLnP.png) this quetion is like the way to convert bt709 to bt2020.
2. I want to convert 8bit to 10bit like the x264. the computer suports only the 8 |16|32 bit.so which kinde of data type to save the 10bit .someone said that we use the 16bit ,the last six bit we use zero to fill.is that right ,i dont think thats a good way.many thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. There's no magical way to extend color data to a wider gamut. You could try to "stretch" data from the existing gamut, and the result would achieve the vividness of the wider gamut, but lose accuracy.
2. Normally the three 10-bit channels are packed into a 32-bit integer.

Comment: "Normally the three 10-bit channels are packed into a 32-bit integer." Is that for non-planar (or SDI)?

Comment: @szatmary yes. For planar images, you can store each padded to 16 bits, close-packed (16 values == 160 bits == 5 32-bit words), or somewhere in between. It depends on how you intend to process them, and how pressed you are for space.

Comment: hello szatmary  thanks for your answer. i have a bt709 video , that means i cannot convert it to bt2020 .is that right ? if so i will give up